# El boton no me esta funcionano , pero no me funciona no hace ninguna accion el boton veo el codigo y no le falta nada ayuda plssss.... :CC

Tags: php

```
<? 
include('index2.php');
?>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#marca").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"subcategorias2.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:"idmarca="+$("#marca").val(),
      success: function(opciones){
        $("#modelo").html(opciones);
      }
    })
  });
});
</script>
<br/>
<center><div style="width:60%;"><h4 style="COLOR: #0404B4; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #D0FA58; opacity: 0.8">Ver Aviso Auditado</h4></div></center><br/>
<br/>

<?
$id_p = $_GET["id_p"];
$path2="/CARPETA/CARPETAv2_$id_p"; 




function leerDirectorio($ruta){
if($dir = opendir($ruta)){ 
chdir($ruta);
//Creamos los array de archivos y carpetas 
$archivos=array();
$carpetas=array();
//Leemos todos los elementos del directorio 
while (($leerDir = readdir($dir)) !== false){
  if(!is_dir ($leerDir)) array_push($archivos,$leerDir);
    else array_push($carpetas,$leerDir);
    }
  //Mostrar Archivos 

  foreach($archivos as $aux) 
    {
    ?>

    <a href='../BBDD/CARPETA/preventivo<?=$_GET["id_p"]?>/Preventivo_<?=$aux?>'><?=$aux?></a><br /><?}?>      
    <?
    /* Cerrar directorio */
    closedir($dir);
    } 
}

function leerDirectorioTermino($ruta){
if($dir = opendir($ruta)){ 
chdir($ruta);
//Creamos los array de archivos y carpetas 
$archivos=array();
$carpetas=array();
//Leemos todos los elementos del directorio 
while (($leerDir = readdir($dir)) !== false){
  if(!is_dir ($leerDir)) array_push($archivos,$leerDir);
    else array_push($carpetas,$leerDir);
    }
  //Mostrar Archivos 

  foreach($archivos as $aux) 
    {
    ?>

    <a href='../BBDD/CARPETA/folio_termino_<?=$_GET["id_p"]?>/<?=$aux?>'><?=$aux?></a><br /><?}?>      
    <?
    /* Cerrar directorio */
    closedir($dir);
    } 
}




$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","pcomp","KneTPuxJ77f4YLNX", "BBDD");
$sql123 = "SELECT * , TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  `fecha_ingreso` ) ) /3600 AS horas_sla
FROM avisos_auditados where id_aviso = $id_p";
$result123 = mysql_query($sql123);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result123)) {

  $area = $row["area_derivacion"];
?>
    <table align="center" class="table" style="width: 50%" >
<tr>
<td>Adjuntos de inicio</td>
<td><? echo @leerDirectorio($path2) ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Adjuntos de termino</td>
<td><? echo @leerDirectorioTermino($path3) ?></td>
</tr>

</table><br/> 

   <center><table id="tablabonita" class="table" align="center" style="width: auto">
  <tr>
  <?
$tipo_defecto = $row["tipo_defecto"];
$agencia = $row["agencia"];
$central = $row["central"];
$direccion = $row["direccion"];
$tipo_cable = $row["tipo_cable"];
$cable = $row["cable"];
$arCARPETA = $row["arCARPETA"];
$causa_falla = $row["causa_falla"];


  ?>
                <td>
                    ID Aviso</td>
                <td>
                   <input id="txtID_proy"  style="width:350px;" type="text" readonly="readonly" 
                        value="<?php echo $row["id_aviso"]; ?>" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                    tipo_defecto</td>
                <td>
                   <input id="txtcalle0" style="width:350px;"  type="text" readonly="readonly" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["tipo_defecto"]); ?>" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Agencia
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="txtaltura0" style="width:350px;"  type="text" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["agencia"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Oficina Central
                </td>
                <td>
                 <input id="txthp0" type="text" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" 
                        value="<?php echo $row["central"]; ?>" ></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    Direccion                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtcap0" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo $row["direccion"]; ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Tipo Cable
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txteecc0" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["tipo_cable"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>
                    Cable
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txteecc0" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["cable"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ArCARPETA
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txteecc0" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["arCARPETA"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>
                    Causa Falla
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txteecc0" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["causa_falla"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>
                    Fecha Ingreso
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txteecc0" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["fecha_ingreso"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>
                    Usuario Ingreso aviso
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txteecc0" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["usuario_ingreso_aviso"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>
                 N° Reclamos               </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txteecc0" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["n_clientes_reclamados"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                 Estado               </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtEstado" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["estado"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                 Nombre Gestor               </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtNGestor" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["nom_gestor"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                 Tipo De Ruta              </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtTRuta" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["tipo_ruta"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                 Clientes Afectados               </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtCAfectado" style="width:350px;"  readonly="readonly" type="text" 
                        value="<?php echo utf8_encode($row["n_clientes_afectados"]); ?>" ></td>
            </tr>
      <tr>

</table></center><?
$tipo_cble = $row["tipo_cable"];
}?>

<script lenguaje="javascript">
function AprobadoOK(form)
{ 
document.getElementById('div_es_falla').style.display = 'block';
}
function Rechazo(form)
{ 
document.getElementById('div_es_falla').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<center><h3>Asignación de trabajo</h3>

<fieldset width="700px">
        <legend><center>Seleccione: </center></legend>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="estado" id="Rechazado" onClick="Rechazo(this.form)" value="Rechazado"> No es Falla Masiva
        </label>
    <label>
            <input type="radio" name="estado" id="Aprobado" checked value="Aprobado" onClick="AprobadoOK(this.form)"> Es Falla Masiva
        </label>
 </fieldset></div>
  <br/>
    <div id="div_es_falla">
  <table style="width: 50%;" align="center"><tr>
     <td>
                    Causa de falla </td>
                <td>  <select id="tipo" name="tipo" class="form-control">
                       <option value="Robo">Robo</option>
                       <option value="Readecuacion">Readecuacion</option>
                       <option value="Transferencia">Transferencia</option>
                       <option value="Mantencion">Mantencion</option>
                       <option value="Danos por terceros">Daños por terceros</option>

            </select></td>
            </tr>
   <tr>
              <td>
                    Capacidad Cable </td>
               <td>
                    <input id="capacidad" class="form-control" name="capacidad" type="text" /></td><td><i>El valor de capacidad ingresado <b>debe ser numérico</b></i></td>
            </tr>

      <tr>
              <td>
                    Cuenta 1 </td>
               <td>
                    <input id="c1" name="c1" type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" /></td><td>
                     Ingresar   
    <input type="checkbox" name="chec1"  value="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('c1').disabled=!this.checked;">  </td>
            </tr>

      <tr>
              <td>
                    Cuenta 2 </td>
               <td>
                    <input id="c2" name="c2" type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled"/></td><td>
                     Ingresar   
    <input type="checkbox" name="chec2" value="checkbox"  onclick="document.getElementById('c2').disabled=!this.checked;">  </td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
              <td>
                    Cuenta 3 </td>
               <td>
                    <input id="c3" name="c3" type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled"/></td><td>
                     Ingresar   
    <input type="checkbox" name="chec3" value="checkbox"  onclick="document.getElementById('c3').disabled=!this.checked;">  </td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
              <td>
                    Cuenta 4 </td>
               <td>
                    <input id="c4" name="c4" type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled"/></td><td>
                     Ingresar   
    <input type="checkbox" name="chec4" value="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('c4').disabled=!this.checked;">  </td>
            </tr>
      <tr>
              <td>
                    Cuenta 5 </td>
               <td>
                    <input id="c5" name="c5" type="text"  class="form-control" disabled="disabled"/></br></td><td>
                     Ingresar   
    <input type="checkbox" name="chec5" value="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('c5').disabled=!this.checked;">  </td>
            </tr>
      </table>  
  </div>
  <table align="center" style="width: 50%;" >

            <tr>
               <td>
                     Par:
               </td>
               <td>
                     <select id="par" name="par" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Par Local">Par Local</option>
                            <option value="Par Externo">Par Externo</option>
                     </select>
               </td>
           </tr>

         <tr>
                <td>
                    Comentarios: </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" cols="50" id="obs" name="obs"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
</table>
    <br/>

        <div align="center">
                <input align="center" name="EnviarInfo" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" style="width: 50%"  value="asignar">
        </div>
  </center>

    <?
if ($_POST[EnviarInfo])
{
   $causa_falla = $_POST['causa_falla'];
      $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","pcomp","KneTPuxJ77f4YLNX", "BBDD");
      $causa = $_POST['tipo'];
      $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
      $capacidad = $_POST['capacidad'];
      $tipo_cable = $_POST['tipo_cable'];

      $c1 = $_POST['c1'];
      $c2 = $_POST['c2'];
      $c3 = $_POST['c3'];
      $c4 = $_POST['c4'];
      $c5 = $_POST['c5'];
      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $obs = $_POST['obs'];
      $par = $_POST['par'];

  if ($_POST['estado'] == 'Rechazado'){
        $sql = "UPDATE avisos set estado='Rechazado',  fecha_respuesta_aviso='$date', fecha_cierre='$date'
        , par = '$par' , direccion='$direccion',causa_falla='$causa_falla' tipo_cable= '$tipo_cable' $obs='obs' where id_aviso=$id_p";

        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO historico (id_aviso, fecha, estado, usuario, observaciones) values ('$id_p','$date', 'Rechazado', '$aux', '$obs')";

    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO messageTest (notification, status, Fecha, Relevancia, Id_aviso, nivel_usuario, prueba) values ('El aviso $id_p ha sido localizado y se cierra por no ser falla de planta externa.','unread','$date', 'Urgente', '$id_p', '5', '$aux')";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) and mysqli_query($link, $sql2) and mysqli_query($link, $sql4)){

                echo "<script>alert('Cambios realizados', 'asignar FALLA')</script>"; 

            } else{

                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }

              $yourURL="editar_auditado_id.php?id=$aux";
              //echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
            echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;url=$yourURL'/>"; 



    }
    else if ($_POST['estado'] == 'Aprobado'){

        if ($c1 == " " && $c2 == " " && $c3 == " " && $c4 == " " && $c5 == " " ) {

            echo "<script>alert('Debe ingresar una cuenta como minimo', 'Debe ingresar una cuenta')</script>";

        }else {

            $contadorCuentas = 0;

            if ($c1 == " " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c2 == " " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c3 == " " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c4 == "  " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c5 == " " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }


            $sql = "UPDATE avisos_auditados set estado='Aprobado', fecha_respuesta_aviso='$date', cuenta1='$c1', cuenta2='$c2',cuenta3='$c3',cuenta4='$c4',cuenta5='$c5', capacidad='$capacidad', causa_falla='$causa_falla',Causa='$tipo',  par = '$par', direccion = '$direccion', tipo_cable='$tipo_cable' where id_aviso=$id_p";

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO historico (id_aviso, fecha, estado, usuario, observaciones) 
                     VALUES ('$id_p','$date', 'Aprobado FALLA', '$aux', '$obs')";

            $sql4 = "INSERT INTO messageTest (notification, status, Fecha, Relevancia, Id_aviso, nivel_usuario, prueba, estado_aviso) 
                     VALUES ('El Aviso $id_p ha sido verificado y se encuentra en estado de Aprobado  ','unread','$date', 'Urgente', '$id_p', '5', '$aux', 'Aprobado FALLA')";


            if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) and mysqli_query($link, $sql2) and mysqli_query($link, $sql4)){

                echo "<script>alert('Cambios realizados', 'asignar FALLA')</script>"; 

            } else{

                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }

              $yourURL="editar_auditado_id?id=$aux";
              //echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
            echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;url=$yourURL'/>"; 

            }

    }


}

$sql_aux_aux = "SELECT * FROM  'historico' where id_aviso = $id_p";
echo '<div class="container">
      <div class="table-responsive">';
echo '<h4 align="left">Historico</h4>';
echo'<br/><center>';

        echo'<table  id="tablabonita" class="table">';
        echo'<th> ID Fecha</th><th> Estado </th><th> Usuario </th><th> Observaciones </th>';
        $result_aux = mysql_query($sql_aux_aux);
     while ($xx = mysql_fetch_array($result_aux)) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$xx['fecha'].'</td><td>'.$xx['estado'].'</td><td>'.$xx['usuario'].'</td><td>'.utf8_encode($xx['observaciones']).'</td></tr>';
     }
     echo '</table></center></div></div>';
?>
```

Comment: Podrías poner mas o menos donde esta la parte del codigo referente al botón? Hay muchas cosas que al parecer no tienen mucho que ver con tu pregunta, por lo cual no puedo encontrsr el lugar de donde podría estar el error.

Comment: Por favor empieza por mejorar tu título

Comment: Lee por favor [ask]. De que boton estas hablando? hay un monton de codigo aca y no se sabe que no funciona, que tiene que hacer, cuando y que no hace.

Answer (score -1):

```
        <div align="center">
                <input align="center" name="EnviarInfo" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" style="width: 50%"  value="asignar">
        </div>
  </center>

    <?
if ($_POST[EnviarInfo])
{
   $causa_falla = $_POST['causa_falla'];
      $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","pcomp","KneTPuxJ77f4YLNX", "BBDD");
      $causa = $_POST['tipo'];
      $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
      $capacidad = $_POST['capacidad'];
      $tipo_cable = $_POST['tipo_cable'];

      $c1 = $_POST['c1'];
      $c2 = $_POST['c2'];
      $c3 = $_POST['c3'];
      $c4 = $_POST['c4'];
      $c5 = $_POST['c5'];
      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $obs = $_POST['obs'];
      $par = $_POST['par'];

  if ($_POST['estado'] == 'Rechazado'){
        $sql = "UPDATE avisos set estado='Rechazado',  fecha_respuesta_aviso='$date', fecha_cierre='$date'
        , par = '$par' , direccion='$direccion',causa_falla='$causa_falla' tipo_cable= '$tipo_cable' $obs='obs' where id_aviso=$id_p";

        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO historico (id_aviso, fecha, estado, usuario, observaciones) values ('$id_p','$date', 'Rechazado', '$aux', '$obs')";

    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO messageTest (notification, status, Fecha, Relevancia, Id_aviso, nivel_usuario, prueba) values ('El aviso $id_p ha sido localizado y se cierra por no ser falla de planta externa.','unread','$date', 'Urgente', '$id_p', '5', '$aux')";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) and mysqli_query($link, $sql2) and mysqli_query($link, $sql4)){

                echo "<script>alert('Cambios realizados', 'asignar juego')</script>"; 

            } else{

                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }

              $yourURL="editar_auditado_id.php?id=$aux";
              //echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
            echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;url=$yourURL'/>"; 



    }
    else if ($_POST['estado'] == 'Aprobado'){

        if ($c1 == " " && $c2 == " " && $c3 == " " && $c4 == " " && $c5 == " " ) {

            echo "<script>alert('Debe ingresar una cuenta como minimo', 'Debe ingresar una cuenta')</script>";

        }else {

            $contadorCuentas = 0;

            if ($c1 == " " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c2 == " " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c3 == " " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c4 == "  " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }

            if ($c5 == " " ) {

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 0;
            }else{

                $contadorCuentas = $contadorCuentas + 1;

            }


            $sql = "UPDATE avisos_auditados set estado='Aprobado', fecha_respuesta_aviso='$date', cuenta1='$c1', cuenta2='$c2',cuenta3='$c3',cuenta4='$c4',cuenta5='$c5', capacidad='$capacidad', causa_falla='$causa_falla',Causa='$tipo',  par = '$par', direccion = '$direccion', tipo_cable='$tipo_cable' where id_aviso=$id_p";

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO historico (id_aviso, fecha, estado, usuario, observaciones) 
                     VALUES ('$id_p','$date', 'Aprobado juego', '$aux', '$obs')";

            $sql4 = "INSERT INTO messageTest (notification, status, Fecha, Relevancia, Id_aviso, nivel_usuario, prueba, estado_aviso) 
                     VALUES ('El Aviso $id_p ha sido verificado y se encuentra en estado de Aprobado  ','unread','$date', 'Urgente', '$id_p', '5', '$aux', 'Aprobado juego')";


            if(mysqli_query($link, $sql) and mysqli_query($link, $sql2) and mysqli_query($link, $sql4)){

                echo "<script>alert('Cambios realizados', 'asignar juego')</script>"; 

            } else{

                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }

              $yourURL="editar_auditado_id?id=$aux";
              //echo ("<script>location.href='$yourURL'</script>");
            echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;url=$yourURL'/>"; 

            }

    }


}

$sql_aux_aux = "SELECT * FROM  'historico' where id_aviso = $id_p";
echo '<div class="container">
      <div class="table-responsive">';
echo '<h4 align="left">Historico</h4>';
echo'<br/><center>';

        echo'<table  id="tablabonita" class="table">';
        echo'<th> ID Fecha</th><th> Estado </th><th> Usuario </th><th> Observaciones </th>';
        $result_aux = mysql_query($sql_aux_aux);
     while ($xx = mysql_fetch_array($result_aux)) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$xx['fecha'].'</td><td>'.$xx['estado'].'</td><td>'.$xx['usuario'].'</td><td>'.utf8_encode($xx['observaciones']).'</td></tr>';
     }
     echo '</table></center></div></div>';
?>
```

esa es la programcion del btn

Comment: No uses la zona de respuestas para complementar tu pregunta, dale editar a tu pregunta y añade esto ahí

Answer (score -1):

No pude encontrar el lugar del código que pusiste arriba, pero intenta con esto como base como una manera de hacer algo al clickear el botón. Espero que te sirva, y una recomendación seria que intentes enviar el código un poco mas ordenado para que sea mas fácil seguir lo que quieres hacer y explicar un poco mas que necesitas para poder ayudarte.

```
 <form action="" method="post">

<input type="submit" name="EnviarInfo" value="asignar" />


<?php
 if (isset($_POST['EnviarInfo'])) {
 //Aqui comienza con tu codigo, esta es una manera de hacerlo.
  }
 ?>
```